# Casual Khmer language classes or language exchange in Siem Reap?

Tags: study, languages, cambodia, siem-reap

As always on my travels I like to study the local language, as usual I don't have a budget that allows the prices of "proper" courses or individual tutors.

So I'm wondering if there's some organization or club that meets to help foreigners learn Khmer, perhaps in exchange for helping with English, or a small cover charge for the venue or buying food and/or drinks at the venue.

I believe there are a lot of expats here, which can often mean such things might exist.

Comment: I assume you've already looked at the "usual" resources for language exchanges, such as meetup.com and couchsurfing? These are quite popular for this sortof thing in Europe. I have no idea about Asia.

Comment: I looked at Meetup but didn't think about CouchSurfing. I'll check that out now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not exactly casual, there's an organization called "[Learn Khmer Language - Siem Reap](https://www.facebook.com/learnkhmerREP/?fref=ts)" that's specialized in teaching the Khmer language to foreigners. The organization [seems to be active](https://www.facebook.com/learnkhmerREP/photos/a.102204606534961.4353.101644959924259/1015891425166270/?type=3&theater) as of late 2016. Their fees per hour are:

> 4$ with a group of 3-4 people
>
> 5$ with a group of 2 people
>
> 8$ for individual

I believe $4 would be small enough for most Westerners to count as a "small cover charge".

Comment: Yes that is indeed cheap enough that I would've gone had I known about it while I was there!